# Linking MYSQL Database Query to images

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to create a drop down list of items that will bring back specific information including an image about that particular item.

I have a list of cities associated with various data about population. That list is pulled back when selected from the drop down menu, however, I also need a way to make a specific image to appear as well.

How to make it so that selecting a city from the drop-down menu will get you various infographics about that city and the image?

Comment: I'd use the JavaScript change event on a `<select>` box, which then fetches the image/text content via JavaScript. That way the menu selection will be reflected in real-time, rather than needing form submission.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to post an image tag with the information that's already posted. You say that:

> That list is pulled back when selected from the drop down menu

so when it's pulled back, in the data you send about the city, add an `<img>` element:

```
<img src="your/uploaded/image/path.jpg" alt="city image">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply add images to your data in MySql you may use the LOAD_FILE function and give the complete path of the image from your system.